# LINQ to SQL "1 of 2 Updates failed" on "SubmitChanges()"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am updating an object of type X and its children Y using LINQ to SQL and then submitting changes and getting this error

Example Code

```
X objX = _context.X.ToList().Where(x => x.DeletedOn == null).First();
objX.DeletedOn = DateTime.Now;

EntitySet<Y> objYs = objX.Ys;
Y objY = objYs[0];
objY.DeletedOn = DateTime.Now;

_context.SubmitChanges();
```

On SubmitChanges() I get an exception "1 of 2 Updates failed", no other information as to why that happened. Any ideas?

Also the exception type is 
ChangeConflictException

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sooo what was the cause of the problem
- A trigger

I did a sql profiler and saw that

When ObjY's DeletedOn property got updated a trigger updated
ObjX's property (value in table) called CountOfX

which led to an error as the SQL created by LINQ to SQL had the old CountOfX value in it.

Hence the conflict.

If you ever get this error - SQL profiler is the best place to start your investigation

*ALSO NOT RELATED TO THE QUESTION*
I am testing LINQ to SQL and ADO.net Framework, weirdly this error happened in LINQ to SQL but not in ADO.net framework. But I like LINQ to SQL for its Lazy Loading. Waiting for EF to get outta beta

Comment: The reason for the error not happening in ADO.net framework
as it only uses the EntityKey value to make updates 
i.e. is the WHERE Condition only checks for the entity value, not for every column value like LINQ2SQL

Comment: So is there anyway to avoid this error other than avoid triggers completely?

Comment: See this link for information about conflicts in LinqToSQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527347/linq-changeconflictexception-occurs-when-submitting-datacontext-changes

Comment: There is a way to control the whole process. See this link for a better work-around: https://debugmode.net/2011/06/27/resolving-concurrency-conflicts-in-linq/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the cause of the error may be exactly, but there seem to be a number of problems with the example you've provided.

- Using ToList() before the Where() method would cause your context to read the entire table from the DB into memory, convert it to an array; and then in the same line you immediately call Where which will discard the rows you've loaded, but don't need. Why not just:

  _context.X.Where(...
- The Where method will return multiple items, but the second line in the example doesn't appear to be iterating through each item individually.  It appears to be setting the  DeletedOn property for the collection itself, but the collection wouldn't have such a property. It should fail right there.
- You are using DateTime.Now twice in the code. Not a problem, except that this will produce ever so slightly different date values each time it is called. You should call DateTime.Now once and assign the result to a variable so that everything you use it on gets identical values.
- At the point where you have "Y objY = objYs[0]" it will fail if there are no items in the Y collection for any given X. You'd get an index out of bounds exception on the array.

So given this example, I'm not sure if anyone could speculate as to why code modeled after this example might be breaking.

Comment: 1st bullet point agreed
2nd bullet point agreed to. The example was written incorrectly I have updated it since, but the code is compiling in real likfe.
3rd bullet point yup the purpose of this is to test if saving will cascade
4th Yes there are items in the collection

The exception rises at SubmitChanges() I know that, except that the error itself doesnt reveal a lot.

Comment: I figured it was running correctly in your real code (otherwise you'd not get to the submit where you reported the erro). the example didn't give enough information for us to really help you out since there were other problem with the example. Glad you seem to have worked it out though :)

Comment: I had the same error when trying to delete. I sent a `List<T>` into the `DeleteAllOnSubmit()` method, it worked out great from the start, but after a month I got this error. It worked when I changed from `List<T>` to `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

In LINQ2SQL Data Context diagram select the Entity and the field where the count is stored. (A denormalized figure)

Now set the UpdateCheck = Never.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of issue. I was debugging running single lines at a time. It turned out another process was modifying this record.

My manual debugging process was slowing down the normal speed of the function. When I ran it all the way to a line after the SubmitChanges method, it succeeded.

My scenario would be less common, but the nature of this error relates to the record becoming superceded by another function/process. In my case it was another process.