# Linq ChangeConflictException occurs when submitting DataContext changes

Tags: linq-to-sql, concurrency

```
System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: 2 of X updates failed.
  at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
  at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
  at PROJECT.Controllers.HomeController.ClickProc(Int32 id, String code, String n)
```

This is what I get very often. This action is done thousands of times a day, and I get this exception about once every 5 seconds. From what I understand it happens when something changes in the database in the period between creating `DataContext` and updating it. Am I right?

How can I fix it?

**Update**

I just debugged the error and found the following:

```
Table name: dbo.Stats
current value: 9852039
original value: 9852038
database value: 9852039
```

The Stats table is updated constantly. So how can I still make LINQ save the changes. With "classical" SQL Server access through `SqlDataCommand` I never had problems like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to optimistic concurrency. You can change this behavior but understand what it does before you do it.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/05/22/intro-to-linq-to-sql-optimistic-concurrency/