# 1 of x updates failed vs row not found or changed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm getting an inconsistent error in a program using linq on submitchanges that says "1 of x updates failed". I've done some research on this and most of what I've found suggests that this is caused by data being used by the open data context being changed from elsewhere while the data is in memory. This makes sense in my case as the data context is open for a while and the table is being used by other programs.

I did a test however to try and replicate this by explicitly changing a row while a data context is open then trying to submit changes. The exception I get in this case is not the "1 of x updates failed" but instead "row not found or changed". I was curious if someone could tell me what the difference is between the two and how I can replicate the "1 of x updates failed" error?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1899269/887092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did some more testing and it seems that the "row not found or changed" exception is thrown either when there is only one row pending an update in the data context or when the row in question is the first to be updated.  In a case when looping through and updating several rows, then calling submitchanges the "1 of x updates failed" exception is thrown instead... assuming it's not the first update that failed. Hope that makes sense.